# Permission Settings to protect Shared Folders from Ransomware on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, backup, permissions

This question has been asked here a few different ways, but I couldn't find one that specifically addresses this for Windows 10 ACL / permissions.

In our work environment we have individual machines make backup images onto a shared folder on a Windows 10 machine that acts as a file server and only that client machine/user has access to that folder.

The concern, of course, is that if the client is ransomware attacked it could access that shared folder and encrypt / overwrite the backup files.

It would seem that using the fine grained special permissions in Windows 10 would make it possible to create a new file and store the backup, but prevent that file from being encrypted and overwritten / deleted?

Comment: The only protection against ransomware is offline backups.  Any location a client has the permissions to write to which is a necessary permissions when you backup the files on that client is a location ransomware will also have permissions to write to since the ransomware has the same permissions as the user who ran it. So the only way to protect against ransomware is to have offline backups that cannot be accessed. A server that has access to volumes, that CANNOT be accessed by anyone on your network (assumes a AD domain), could be considered as a safe backup location. Offline is best.

Comment: You're dreaming if you think you can protect against ransomware.

Comment: Back up that folder. Rotate the backups. If I was building something 'new' for this, I'd backup to a VM, or better yet, a linux/smb/ZFS file server and take snapshots regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some time to test various scenarios last night and contrary to some comments that have been posted here, it does seem that you can control permissions via Windows ACL to protect a shared network folder from ransomware infected clients overwriting and encrypting the data in the shared folder while still allowing write permissions.

The standard caveat applies that offline backups are the best overall approach and that if your entire network (or the host/server) is compromised, this solution does not protect you.

The solution is using the Advanced Security Settings and disabling Write, Delete, Read & Change Permissions and Take Ownership.  With these settings the client machine can read and create new files, but it can't rename or change any existing files.

A possible issue here is that if you are using any kind of automated backup approach (i.e. backup/imaging software, file compression archive utility, etc...) and that program writes into the destination directory using a temporary file, it will fail when it tries to rename and/or delete the temporary file. A possible workaround would be for the client machine to create the backup image/archive locally and then use a script to copy final completed image/archive/files into the Windows share and (optionally) delete the local copy.

Example of how to set the permissions to achieve this here:

[image: Advanced Security Permissions for Windows 10]

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with with this exact scenario, as have many others in this forum, I suspect.

If a person can login as a user and read/write to server files, the files are at risk. I.e., if a user can edit a word document, then can encrypt it.

Rather than change server access permissions (they should be set up as minimum privilege needed), most organizations are changing what users can access. Our organization blocked all of Google Drive, for example. This isn't a great solution, but it's worked so far (knock on wood).

If it's just local backups you're concerned about, creating a 'backup user' that solely holds write permissions to the backup volume technically works, although I haven't tried this.

Ultimate solution is segregated incremental cloud backups.

Comment: How does blocking Google Drive prevent files on a server from being encrypted?  It prevents data loss but I don't see the connection to preventing ransomware

Comment: By data loss I mean data theft by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Windows *does* have a feature called "Controlled Folder Access", if you go into Settings > Windows Security > Virus & Threat Protection > near the bottom click "Manage Ransomware Protection" and see the feature in there.

This sets 'protected folders' that will basically make it so any app that wants to access those folders will need to be approved, which would require admin access. It's supposed to automatically allow safe apps but I found that almost every single one needed manual approval to add to the allowed list.

*However*, the big drawback to this feature is you *cannot* remove any of the default protected folders, which includes all the libraries (videos, documents, etc). You can add custom folders and remove them, but not the defaults. Which might make the feature more hassle than it's worth if you only care about protecting a specific location.

Comment: Thanks - I considered this but the drawbacks are significant and I did also worry that some future clever malware might learn to exploit/circumvent this system through privilege escalation if the client is infected.  Which is why I was looking to use permissions on the host/server to protect the files from a malicious infected client.